# Using an input$table_rows_selected and a selectInput to print a graph (Shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I use a first SQL query to load a selecInput list with items

I create a graph in shiny resulting on the first SQL query including the selected item into the selectInput list

Then I create a dataTable with the whole selectInput List and I wish use the input$table_rows_selected function (clicking in the DT Table row view) to update this graph

How can I trace graph either with the selectInput object or with the input$table_rows_selected function from the DT table ?

For now I can just trace my graph from the selectInput list

Thank you for your help

Here my UI.R :

```
 sidebarPanel(
  uiOutput("selectComp") #My selectInput list
           ),

 mainPanel(
  DT::dataTableOutput("table"), #My Table 
  plotlyOutput("plot")) # My graph
   ))
```

Here my server.R :

```
     refDataFrame <- reactive({
     data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

     SQL query searching all STEP_NAME items
     odbcClose(data_testeur)

    Ref_comp
   })

   output$selectComp <- renderUI(

      selectInput("comp","Select the step", choices= refDataFrame()
      [["STEP_NAME"]]) # Load the selecInput list with items

     ) 

     output$Table <- DT::renderDataTable({

     data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")

      SQL query to feed my dataTable with a column including all items 
                                                             STEP_NAME
      Close connexion data_testeur

      DT::datatable(cpk_total,...) # Formating table
        )

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({

      data_testeur <- odbcConnect(input$base, uid="uid")
      another SQL query to trace the graph for 1 STEP_NAME selected
      Close connexion data_testeur

    graph <- ....

    )
```

How can I trace graph either with the selectInput object or with the input$table_rows_selected function from the DT table ?

For now I can just trace my graph from the selectInput list

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to take input from either selectInput or if the table is clicked from input$table_rows_selected

The last is `NULL` if no row is selected so you should probably add some code similar to this in your rendering function

```
if(!is.null(input$table_rows_selected) ) { #test if table is clicked
  #do something with input$table_rows_selected
} else {
  #do something only with selectInput
}
```

hope this helps other wise please clarify your question

Comment: Ok, is it correct too like this :  ?                                                        
                 output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    if(length(input$table_rows_selected) > 0)  {
      data <-  input$table_rows_selected
      table_result  <-  SQL query(data)    graph <- table_result                                                                                                      }
else {                                                                                      
  table_result2<-  SQL query(datatable[1,1] )    graph<- table_result2 #Value default for graph   } })